# $f(x)=3x+5$, what is $f(\frac{1-x}{x})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How can I solve this problem?

Should I equalize $x=\frac{1-x}{x}$?

Or find $f(\frac{1-x}{x})=3(\frac{1-x}{x})+5$?

Comment: The second option is the correct one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So, what I must to do if I want to find $f(3)$ for the function $f(\frac{1-x}{x})$?

Comment: I have no idea about what that question means.

Comment: I mean, I find the function $f(\frac{1-x}{x})$ as $f(\frac{1-x}{x})=\frac{3+2x}{x}$. I want to say that new function $g(x)=\frac{3+2x}{x}$ and I want to find $g(3)$. Is that legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x) = 3x+5$ , taking $\left(\dfrac{1-x}x\right)  = y $ , we get :

$$f(y) = 3y+5\implies f\left(\dfrac{1-x}x\right) = 3\left(\dfrac{1-x}x\right) +5$$

$$\color{#24f}{f\left(\dfrac{1-x}x\right)  = \dfrac 3x +2}$$

Comment: What is $f(3), f(0)$ for the function $f$ that provides $f(\frac{1-x}{x})=\frac{3}{x}+2$ correlation?

Comment: Ok, let me try something else. We have a function $f$ that is defined as $f(\frac{1-x}{x})=\frac{3}{x}+2$. My question what is $f(0), f(3)$?

Comment: Can you explain how do you find these results? I don't get how you do that :/

Comment: Do you find what is $x$ for $\frac{1-x}{x}=3$ to find $f(3)$?

Comment: No problem, we all do :P Thanks for your verification. So, $f(3)=14$ ans $f(0)=5$, is it correct?

Comment: @MuhammedÇ.TUFAN Yes

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help @TheDemoniz_Hermit 